# Почему тут return в getListFromNet() вызывается быстрее чем onResponse?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

```
object RetrofitProvider {

        private var list = listOf<Poi>()

        fun getListFromNet(): List<Any> {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://kiparo.ru/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

            val jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi::class.java)

            val call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getCars(3333.0, 342.0, 3242.0, 3453.0)

            call.enqueue(object : Callback<CarResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<CarResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    println("AAA --------> onFailure error!!")
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<CarResponse>, response: Response<CarResponse>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        list = response.body()!!.poiList
                        println("AAA -------->  onResponse "+ list)
                    }
                }
            })

            println("AAA -------->  return list "+ list)

            return list
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что call.enqueue асинхронная операция, onResponse вызывается только тогда, когда придут данные из сети

Comment: а как поступить? спасибо!

Comment: Сложно сказать, т.к. я не знаю в каком контексте вы используете RetrofitProvider. Если в активити/фрагменте, то можно возвращать из функции call вместо list, а call.enqueue вызывать из активити/фрагменте и в onResponse и onFailure делать нужную работу с листом (эти методы вызываются на главном потоке). А можно в функцию getListFromNet передавать свой коллбек (в виде лямды, например), который будет выполнятся при выполнении onResponse

Comment: спасибо большое!